# Intuitive introduction to gauge symmetry for non-physicist?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

In [this video](https://youtu.be/YP-tPE7WO64?t=427), Lawrence Krauss explains for a popular audience that the laws of electromagnetism are uniquely determined by assuming that we can "change the rules locally" (he uses as an example, that we can give one electron a positive charge, while "taking this into account when calculating its effect on other electrons and protons", without changing the laws of physics).

I don't really get what he means, because he explains it in such a non-mathematical way.

**Is there a simple introduction to this idea, that the laws of electromagnetism are uniquely determined by certain symmetry assumptions?**

ps. I am not a physicist but I understand basic group theory from a mathematical point of view.

Answer (score 1):

There are three books that I would recommend, the first is by Sean Carroll: "[The particle at the end of the universe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0142180300)".

The second is tougher to get through and it's Frank Close's "[The Infinity Puzzle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465063829)". This has a wider scope than Carroll's book, but they complement each other pretty well, if you read Carroll first.

Neither of them are inherently math based, which I know you ask for (but look them up on the Amazon "Look inside the Book" feature, however, they do use more math than most), but use math where necesssary. I would say they are worth reading, especially the Close book.

The popular science, but with a solid math basis book, is "[Deep Down Things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080187971X)" by Bruce Schumm, which pretty much starts by using the complex plane  to introduce abstract spaces, and then uses covariant differentiation to lead on to and describe all of the force carriers.